# Como criar um loop VBA para acrescentar itens

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, google-sheets

Tenho uma planilha **(P1)** e quero exportar por vez 20 itens dela para outra planilha **(P2)**.

Porém com **copy + paste** cada vez que novos itens são acrescentados na **P1**, os que já haviam sido copiados para a P2 somem.

*Minha idéia é:*

Rodou o código, ***acrescentam mais vinte itens*** da P1 na **P2**

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Salve, meu caro! Em geral, em aplicações Windows, quando você copia algo, essa coisa não some. Isso só ocorre se você Recortar. Pode dar mais detalhes sobre o sumiço das informações copiadas? Será que não estão sendo recortadas, em vez de copiadas?

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que as duas planilhas estão no mesmo arquivo, expliquei os passos no código:

```
Sub copy-paste()
    Dim p1 As Worksheet
    Dim p2 As Worksheet
    Dim itens As Range
    Dim linha As Long
    
    ' Definir as planilhas P1 e P2
    Set p1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("P1") 
    Set p2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("P2") 
    
    ' Copiar os 20 itens da P1 para a P2
    linha = p2.Cells(p2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' achar próxima linha vazia da P2 (na primeira coluna, no caso a coluna "A")
    Set itens = p1.Range("A1:A20") ' selecionar os próximos 20 itens da P1
    itens.Copy p2.Cells(linha, "A") ' copiar os itens para a próxima linha vazia na coluna A da P2  
    ' limpar "ctrl+c"'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  
End Sub
```